# Is there any proof of global convergence for 1D convex numeric optimization using cross entropy method?

Tags: sampling, optimization, cross-entropy, importance-sampling

Suppose we have the following 1D numeric optimization problem:
$min_{x} f(x)$ given $0< x \le x_{MAX}$ where $f(x)$ is a convex function. And I want to apply the cross-entropy method to optimize this problem (assume that I am using smoothing parameter $\alpha$). How can I prove that it will converge to gloabl optima?